# How to count and group by

Tags: sql, count, group-by

As you can see in this image below, I need to count how many number '1' is on every column, the number '1' means that the person interviewed feels secure at Home(AP_4_01),Workplace(AP4_4_02) and so on..

Number 2 = Insecure

Number 3 = Doesn't Apply

Number 9 = Didn't Answer

```
+----------+----------------------+
| Columns  | Numbers of persons   |
+----------+----------------------+
| AP4_4_01 | 312                  |
| AP4_4_02 | 232                  |
| AP4_4_03 | 345                  |
| AP4_4_0X | XXX                  |
+----------+----------------------+
```

---

[image: Table with the data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `SUM` function on some case statements

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN AP_4_01 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN AP_4_02 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   ...etc
FROM Table
```

To get a result set like the one in your question, you will need to use the `UNPIVOT` function, or you can transpose it in excel.

Comment: Thanks! This did the job.